# Import missing data from a .txt file into existing data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, import

I have a data frame with this structure:

```
structure(list(rowNumber = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), rowLabel = c("IPU1", 
"IPU1", "IPU1", "IPU1", "IPU1", "IPU1"), SampleTime = c(1.317302056, 
1.327302056, 1.337302056, 1.347302056, 1.357302056, 1.367302056
), F0 = c(238.4728491, 238.4728491, 238.4728491, 238.4728491, 
230.4871243, 235.301327), mother = c("french", "french", "french", 
"french", "french", "french"), level = c("bil", "bil", "bil", 
"bil", "bil", "bil"), name = c("clemence", "clemence", "clemence", 
"clemence", "clemence", "clemence"), task = c("film", "film", 
"film", "film", "film", "film"), lang = c("fr", "fr", "fr", "fr", 
"fr", "fr"), f0st = c(94.7721745186803, 94.7721745186803, 94.7721745186803, 
94.7721745186803, 94.1825081930544, 94.5403877585993), gender = c("F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), f0stnorm = c(1.11260538951537, 1.11260538951537, 
1.11260538951537, 1.11260538951537, 0.934191841072306, 1.0424743738019
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

But I realised that some data are missing, for example, I don't have the values for name = alan & task = film & lang = eng but I do have these data in a separate .txt file. Is there a way to import the data from my .txt file directly into the data frame?

Comment: You may read the other data with `read.table` and then use `rbind` or `bind_rows` from `dplyr`

Comment: Thanks. I have managed to read the txt file and have it as a df now. I have never used `rbind` or `bind_rows` and I would also like to make sure the data I import in my first df goes in the correct location so not sure how to write that code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the txt file is has a comma delimiter: Also assuming your df is df1 and txt file is df2.txt

```
library(data.table)

fwrite(df1, "file location/df2.txt", append = TRUE)
df1<-fread(df2.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks. I used `read_delim` to have my txt file as a df. If I use the command you're suggesting, where will the data go in my df1? Data in df2 need to be added as rows in df1.

Comment: what this is doing is, taking df1 and appending it to the data in df2.  Then it rereads the raw file in as df1 which would have everything combines